# angularjs file size

Tags: angularjs, size

Citation from angularjs.org / faq

"How big is the angular.js file that I need to include?
The size of the file is < 36KB compressed and minified."

But all version from any place from the internet (CDN-s, code.angularjs.org, etc.) is bigger then 120kb (latest 1.3.x).

So, the FAQ is just marketing, or outdated, or what?

Thank you!

Comment: Lol. Just the core file is 28000 lines of code. They were just kidding around.

Comment: The FAQ page now states "The size of the file is ~50KB compressed and minified." which matches up to @danikoren's answer

Answer (score 2):

when using this file (currently latest)
http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.min.js

you get almost 49kb minified and gzipped 
you can check it here:
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Best

Answer (score 1):

There is no version of AngularJS (out of the box) that is less than 36kb. Even the first version of AngularJS (v 0.10.0) that you still can download is 65kb. This is probably a marketing thing of AngularJS.

Comment: Don't forget that such content should be gzipped when send through the web. So final sent size is just 30kb.